# 403 Forbidden using codeigniter on IIS

Tags: php, iis, codeigniter-3

**This is what I am working with:**

- Window Server 2016
- SQL Server 2017
- IIS 10
- Codeigniter 3

**This is what I have done:**

Installed IIS URL Rewrite 2.1

Modified the web.config file that is located in the application
   folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Index">
            <match url="^(.*)$"/>
            <conditions>
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:1}"/>
        </rule>                
    </rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Modified the config.php file:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://10.10.0.4/portalci/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Modified the autoload.php file:

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

**The results:**

When I go to http://10.10.0.4/portalci/index.php it works fine. When I remove the index.php I get the following error:
403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Side note: I have spent the last 16 hours and reviewed hundreds of other post to try to resolve this myself.

Comment: You should use .htaccess file. If .htaccess not support then contact your host provider.

Comment: Little confused. I am using IIS. Isn't the .htaccess file for apache?

Comment: Update - I did not have a default document of index.php setup in IIS. 
I can now remove the index.php from http://10.10.0.4/portalci/index.php and it works. 
Bad new is when I try to go to http://10.10.0.4/portalci/index.php/documents/display/dnumber for example I still have to put in the index.php. 
I want it to be clean like this:
http://10.10.0.4/portalci/documents/display/dnumber but I get this error:
404 - File or directory not found.